# passing panda dataframe data to functions and its not outputting the results

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my code, I am trying to extract data from csv file to use in the function, but it doesnt output anything, and gives no error. My code works because I tried it with just numpy array as inputs. not sure why it doesnt work with panda.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

# change the current directory to the directory where the running script file is
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# finding best fit line for y=mx+b by iteration
def gradient_descent(x,y):
    m_iter = b_iter = 1 #starting point
    iteration = 10000
    n = len(x)
    learning_rate = 0.05

    last_mse = 10000

    #take baby steps to reach global minima
    for i in range(iteration):

        y_predicted = m_iter*x + b_iter

        #mse = 1/n*sum([value**2 for value in (y-y_predicted)]) # cost function to minimize
        mse = 1/n*sum((y-y_predicted)**2) # cost function to minimize
        if (last_mse - mse)/mse < 0.001:
            break

        # recall MSE formula is 1/n*sum((yi-y_predicted)^2), where y_predicted = m*x+b
        # using partial deriv of MSE formula, d/dm and d/db 
        dm = -(2/n)*sum(x*(y-y_predicted))
        db = -(2/n)*sum((y-y_predicted))

        # use current predicted value to get the next value for prediction
        # by using learning rate
        m_iter = m_iter - learning_rate*dm 
        b_iter = b_iter - learning_rate*db
        print('m is {}, b is {}, cost is {}, iteration {}'.format(m_iter,b_iter,mse,i))

        last_mse = mse

#x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
#y = np.array([5,7,8,10,13])
#gradient_descent(x,y)

df = pd.read_csv('Linear_Data.csv')
x = df['Area']
y = df['Price']
gradient_descent(x,y)
```

Comment: You need to add return <data you want to return> at the end of the function

Comment: i dont think return is the issue here (and i tried), the problem is in the csv file but i cannot figure out what. I literally type in 2 columns in the csv file and call it x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My code works because I tried it with just numpy array as inputs. not sure why it doesnt work with panda.

Well no, your code also works with pandas dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Area': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Price': [5,7,8,10,13]})
x = df['Area']
y = df['Price']
gradient_descent(x,y)
```

Above will give you the same output as with numpy arrays.

Try to check what's in `Linear_Data.csv` and/or add some `print` statements in the `gradient_descent` function just to check your assumptions. I would suggest to first of all add a `print` statement before the condition with the `break` statement:

```
print(last_mse, mse)
if (last_mse - mse)/mse < 0.001:
    break
```

Comment: 0    2600
1    3000
2    3200
3    3800
4    4000
Name: Area, dtype: int64 0    50000
1    60000
2    70000
3    80000
4    90000
Name: Price, dtype: int64 this is what it shows respectively when I do a print on csv file

Comment: also adding the print statement before the condition gives last_mse = 10000, mse = 4631954641.0

Comment: i figured it out, your comments towards the print statement helped solve the issue. thank you!